# The eclipse synchronized C/C++ project fails to synchronize

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I tried to create synchronized C/C++ project for linux kernel (very big project) with Eclipse kepler, however project synchronization always fails to start between local and remote host (initial files on local host).

I've got the following exception:

> An internal error occurred during: "Remote Synchronization". Exception
>   caught during execution of add command.

However there is no issue if I create synchronized project for small project.
Does any one has an idea what cause this issue?

exception stack trace:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-12-27 11:12:07.376
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Remote Synchronization".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of add command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRemoteSyncConnection.doCommit(GitRemoteSyncConnection.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRemoteSyncConnection.buildRepo(GitRemoteSyncConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRemoteSyncConnection.<init>(GitRemoteSyncConnection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.getSyncConnection(GitSyncService.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.getMergeConflictFiles(GitSyncService.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.synchronize(GitSyncService.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.core.SyncRunner.synchronize(SyncRunner.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.core.SyncManager$SynchronizeJob.run(SyncManager.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LockFailedException: Cannot lock /home/oussama/devel/mylinux/.ptp-sync/index
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.lockDirCache(Repository.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:138)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please check the log at ${workspace}/.metadata/.log. Can you paste relevant exception in your question?

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-12-27 11:12:07.376
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Remote Synchronization".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of add command
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:208)
 at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRemoteSyncConnection.doCommit(GitRemoteSyncConnection.java:577)
 at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRemoteSyncConnection.buildRepo(GitRemoteSyncConnection.java:242) ... I cannot paste the full traceback as the comment length is limited ..

Comment: You may paste the stack trace of the JGit error into your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you asked for? I have given the full log file ...

Comment: I haven't noticed the link in the second comment (gcc/g++ is irrelevant for the issue at hand so I dismissed the whole comment before reading till the end). Anyways, I can't access dropbox from my work so I will need to take a look from home. Note that you may want to contact PTP mailing list.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug in eclipse bug tracking system https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=424701 You may see the full log there

Comment: I guess there is a lock issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your stack trace it appears that EGit is choking on an orphaned lock file:

```
Cannot lock /home/oussama/devel/mylinux/.ptp-sync/index
```

Look for `/home/oussama/devel/mylinus/.ptp-sync/index.lock`.  If it exists, delete it and try synchronizing again.  See also, [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339781).